# passing variables to nasm procedure

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, masm

I have an .asm module and I wanna use its procedures in .c module.
Since I was using MASM my code would look something like:

```
SECTION .text

func PROC arg1: DWORD, arg2:DWORD
...
ret
ENDPROC
```

and in .c module:

```
extern "C"{
    void func (int arg1, int arg2);
}
```

Now I use ubuntu and decided to try NASM. 
So I have the following questions: How can I pass arguments to a procedure in nasm since it's just a label? How can I use variables described under extern "C" in .c module in my NASM code?

I also heard, there is a convention about passing arguments to a procedure using stack. Can I use is somehow here? Would you please give me some examples?

Comment: It all depends. Are you looking to write 64-bit code or 32-bit code on Ubuntu? The calling convention differs depending on the code you want to generate. With _NASM_ you have to understand the calling convention, where as _MASM_ hides most of the details via the PROC statement.

Comment: I was going to write an answer describing the GCC function call ABI on x86 and x86-64, but then I saw `extern "C" { ... }` in a post tagged `C`. Yuk. Those who start with such misconceptions are too wayward to help, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to point out:

- Your assembler procedure is passed arguments through registers, the
  stack or a combination of both. Check your platform ABI.
- The assembler functions you want to call from C typically have an underscore prefix `_`. You can either do this for every function you are going to expose:

`section .text
global _func`

```
_func:
     ; Do stuff
    ret
```

Or via the nasm compile argument (which will do it for all functions) `--prefix _`

- Finally you only need the `extern "C"` if calling from C++ programs.

Have fun!